# Create Nestjs/mongoose expired collection

Tags: mongoose, nest, ttl

I have a collection which stores refresh tokens. I need to document removed after token expired. My mongoose sсhema:

```
@Schema({ versionKey: false})
export class Refresh {
  @Prop()
  userId: string;

  @Prop()
  refreshToken: string;

  @Prop({ index: true, type: Date, default: Date.now, expireAfterSeconds: 3600 })
  createdAt: Date;
}

export const RefreshSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Refresh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand but are you looking for something like this?

```js
// Hook to delete the document after the refresh token expires
RefreshSchema.post("save", async function (doc) {
  if (doc.createdAt.getTime() + 3600 * 1000 < Date.now()) {
    await Refresh.deleteOne({ _id: doc._id });
  }
});
```